# How to save an image with specific id and fetch that image from database through that id in mongo database. thanks for any idea or advice

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have made web application to upload images into mongodb and fetch images from mongo database  to front-end. I am going to upload an image with specific id and those who knows that id and can see the image.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing for my Homepage.
You can use multer for example to upload the images from the browser your node js app. Then I would recommend GridFS to store the Image in Database. GridFS stores the Images in chunks, because mongoDB can only story some few mb of data per object. GridFS will create two collections, one with the chunks and one with the meta data of the image. For example id, filename or something else you like.
Be aware that GridFS work with streams, so sometimes it can be a little bit complicated...